# Gnuplot pm3d - setting gamma as the 4th dimension

Tags: gnuplot

I use pm3d setting in gnuplot to visualize density of wave function in my simulations. Also, recently I visualize second data, the phase of my wave function (cos^2 to be more precise). Everything is on 2d graph with dependency of x-space coordinate and time. Here is the example:

[image: something]

My question is, can I get both data variables into one plot? I was thinking about adjusting gamma level depending of density. Can I get it in few commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefit of drawing `with image` is that the third dimension is automatically mapped to the colored palette. However, the palette is just one-dimensional and there is no way to make it two-dimensional.

## Solution 1

Use the plot style `rgbimage`:

```
plot "data" using x:y:r:g:b with rgbimage
```

It takes three columns to define the red, green and blue component for each data point, so you gain three dimensions to color your plot.
Each component has to be in range [0:255], so you have take care of the scaling.

It is on you to provid the r, g, b value.

### Possible color mapping:

As you want to display complex numbers, you may have a look on the HSV (hue-saturation-value) color space:

[image]

(picture http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/hsv-shading/)

The *hue* is the angle in this plot (perfect for polar component), and the *saturation* determines the radial color grade from white to fully saturated color (perfect for amplitude). The *value* is always 1.

But I have to say, formulas to convert HSV to RGB (i.e. your complex number to RGB) are not that easy, but you'll find them on the web. May be, you also find an other nice and simple mapping of your complex value to RGB.

## Solution 2

Another idea: Use multiplot to overlay two plots. The first is the usual `with image`, the second uses `with rgbalpha`. This type is similar to `with rgbimage` as described above, but with an additional column specifying the transparancy of the color (again, range [0:255])

Here, I overlay a first plot (vertical pattern) with a pure white layer and horizontal transparency pattern:

```
# for using the '++' below
set isosamples 1000
set yrange[-4:4]
set xrange[-4:4] 

# The box would need manual adjustment. I left it out there
unset colorbox


set multiplot
plot '++' u 1:2:(sin($1)) w image 
plot '++' u 1:2:(255):(255):(255):(127+127*sin($2)) w rgbalpha
unset multiplot
```

[image]